# Why $ \lim_{n\to \infty} ({\frac{2}{n}})^n = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left({\frac{2}{n}}\right)^n = 0$$

I see that the denominator goes "faster" to infinity, but is there a way like using the squeeze theory to show that?

thanks

Comment: If $n\ge 2$ then $0\lt \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n \le \frac{2}{n}$. Now Squeeze.

Comment: You have some good answers already, but, for a better understanding of what's going on here, I suggest you estimate $(2/1000)^{1000}$, i.e., your function evaluated at $n=1000$.  Then think about what would happen if you replaced $1000$ with even bigger numbers.

Comment: Because this is clearly so with all number in the open interval ]0,1[

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $0 < (2/n)^n < (2/3)^n$ for all $n > 3$ and $(2/3)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then by the squeeze theorem, $(2/n)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limits of the form $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}q^{n}$; if $(q_n)\to q$, with $\vert q \vert >1$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}q^{n}$ doesn't exist. Otherwise if $(q_n)\to q$, with $\vert q \vert <1$ (i.e, $-1<q<1$), then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}q^{n}\to 0$. The proof is for Bernoulli's inequality. So, in your case $\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right) \to 0$, therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)^{n}\to 0$

Comment: I think you mean $q^n \to 0$.

Comment: it was a mistake, sorry.